# Lync UCWA Api autodiscovey issue

Tags: java, lync, ucwa

I am using ucwa.lync.com api and when i am using url https://lyncdiscover.comapanyname.com
i am getting response as

```
{"AccessLocation":"External","Root":{"Links":[{"href":"https:\/\/something.comapanyname.com\/Autodiscover\/AutodiscoverService.svc\/root\/domain","token":"Domain"},{"href":"https:\/\/something.comapanyname.com\/Autodiscover\/AutodiscoverService.svc\/root\/user","token":"User"}]}}
```

which contains only two links .but accordin to the api it must return three links.

Can any one tell me what is problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

The above result indicates that one of a few possibilities:

- You are not running against Lync Server 2013 with CU1+ installed
- You are running against Lync Server 2013 with CU1+ installed, but final steps were not completed

If it is the first case, UCWA is not enabled prior to Lync Server 2013 CU1.  If it is the second case, I would have your Lync Admins look over [ITAdmin-Configuration](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/ITAdmin-Configuration) specifically about running Bootstrapper.exe (*on each server*) in addition to Enable-CsToplogy.

Comment: Thanks, ShelbyZ... Can u please tell me which java API now i have to use for this problem for sending IM. or other language API to send IM on lync

Comment: Take a look at [ucwa.lync.com](http://ucwa.lync.com) and browse the documentation to get an idea of how to interact with the API.  There is information on how to send an IM using ucwa via at: [KeyTasks-Communication-OutgoingIMCall](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/KeyTasks-Communication-OutgoingIMCall)